# Expand-Collapse Menu Suggestions

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement an expand-collapse ul and li list for a side project I'm working on, and I can't seem to get it to work. I have it so on the li click (page redirect) it collapses the ul, but I can't toggle anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $("#"+tab_id).toggleClass('current');
    })
    $('.collapse-list-unstyled li').click(function(){
        $('.collapse-list-unstyled').hide("slow");
    })


}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list-unstyled components" id="tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-tab="drop-01Submenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Drop-1</a>
           <ul class="collapse-list-unstyled" id="drop-01Submenu">
               <li><a href="#" class="tab-link-a" data-tab="tab-4">LI-1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" class="tab-link-a" data-tab="tab-5">LI-2</a> </li>
           </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are hidding the elements. call `.show()` after adding `.current`.

Comment: @msg yes, but if I add $('.collapse-list-unstyled').show("slow"); to the .dropdown-toggle function, it doesn't allow it to toggle. So essentially what I want is when clicking the ul tag, it toggles open the li and if a li is selected (more importantly the link) it closes the ul.

Answer (score 0):

You can show it the same way you hid it. Just change trigger and change hide to show.
https://codepen.io/richiegarcia/pen/RwWgorE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.collapse-list-unstyled').show("slow");
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $("#" + tab_id).toggleClass('current');
    })
    $('.collapse-list-unstyled li').click(function() {
        $('.collapse-list-unstyled').hide("slow");
    })


});
```

Comment: like I said above though:
if I add $('.collapse-list-unstyled').show("slow"); to the .dropdown-toggle function, it doesn't allow it to toggle. So essentially what I want is when clicking the ul tag, it toggles open the li and if a li is selected (more importantly the link) it closes the ul.

Comment: @j.kells then also toggle the class on `li` click, or `add` in one place, `remove` in the other. Can you put together a working example of the problem?